# How to use Apple remote with Picasa in OS X?

Tags: macos, picasa, apple-remote

I'd like to use Picasa as my picture management application in OS X (version 10.6.7) / 2010 Mac Mini.

But I haven't found a way to use Apple Remote with it (for pausing/resuming the slideshow and manually moving "left" and "right" through the images). None of the buttons seem to respond.

Is there a way to make the remote play nice with Picasa? It's working with iPhoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Sofa Control](http://www.caseapps.com/sofacontrol/).

Comment: Thanks. I quite like the possibilities. I fiddled with the scripts and got Picasa working just the way I like it. For future reference - the fully functional version is $15 (without the licence it functions for 20 minutes each start)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [iRed Lite](http://www.filewell.com/iRedLite/).